Mejor estructura de datos para abordar un problema
Necesito resolver el siguiente problema usando estructuras de datos:
obtener los primeros 5 partidos con mayor cantidad de goles (sumar goles de ambos
equipos) y de cada competición que haya en la base de datos. De haber más de 5
por igualdad en cantidad de goles, filtrar por fecha, dejando los más recientes. De
haber similitud de fechas, filtrar por criterio programador.
para esto cuento con una base de datos CSV con bastante informacion sobre partidos con el siguiente formato
Jornada,Fecha,Equipo Local,Goles Local,Goles Visitante,Equipo Visitante,Competicion

mas allá de como se deba implementar en codigo, lo que necesitos es alguna estrategia para conseguir esa consigna en el menor tiempo de ejecucion.

¿un árbol de búsqueda balanceada? https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rbol_rojo-negro

A caso es un problema de Omega UP? Por cierto, qué intentaste?

Tus requerimientos no son de la estructura de datos, al fin y al cabo si tienes esa colección de datos los vas a tener que guardar. Tus requerimientos son de ordenación, tus datos deben ordenarse en base a:

Suma de goles.
Jornada.

Por simplificar usaré un objeto que contenga sólo esos datos, pero puedes extender los datos a tu antojo pues no afectarán a la ordenación:
struct partido
{
    using fecha = std::chrono::year_month_day;

    unsigned goles_local{}, goles_visitante{};
    fecha jornada{};
};

Si defines un operador de comparación para ese objeto, de manera que siga tus criterios:
bool operator<(const partido &p1, const partido &p2)
{
    const auto goles1 = p1.goles_local + p1.goles_visitante;
    const auto goles2 = p2.goles_local + p2.goles_visitante;

    return std::tie(goles1, p1.jornada) > std::tie(goles2, p2.jornada);
}

Podrás guardar los partidos en un std::set, que por defecto ordena. Si de este contenedor lees los N primeros datos, ya tienes tu objetivo cumplido:
using namespace std::chrono;

std::set<partido> partidos
{
    {0, 0, {2024y, October, 1d}},
    {0, 1, {2024y, October, 2d}},
    {2, 0, {2024y, October, 3d}},
    {0, 3, {2024y, October, 4d}},
    {4, 0, {2024y, October, 5d}},
    {1, 3, {2024y, October, 6d}},
    {0, 0, {2024y, October, 7d}},
    {2, 4, {2024y, October, 8d}},
    {0, 4, {2024y, October, 9d}},
    {3, 0, {2024y, October, 10d}},
    {0, 2, {2024y, October, 11d}},
    {1, 0, {2024y, October, 12d}},
    {0, 0, {2024y, October, 13d}},
};

for (const auto &p : partidos)
    std::cout << std::format("Partido {}/{}/{}, L {} V {}\n",
        p.jornada.day(), p.jornada.month(), p.jornada.year(),
        p.goles_local, p.goles_visitante);

El código anterior muestra la siguiente salida:
Partido 08/Oct/2024, L 2 V 4
Partido 09/Oct/2024, L 0 V 4
Partido 06/Oct/2024, L 1 V 3
Partido 05/Oct/2024, L 4 V 0
Partido 10/Oct/2024, L 3 V 0
Partido 04/Oct/2024, L 0 V 3
Partido 11/Oct/2024, L 0 V 2
Partido 03/Oct/2024, L 2 V 0
Partido 12/Oct/2024, L 1 V 0
Partido 02/Oct/2024, L 0 V 1
Partido 13/Oct/2024, L 0 V 0
Partido 07/Oct/2024, L 0 V 0
Partido 01/Oct/2024, L 0 V 0

